# Discord.js error "message is not defined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

**Hi, I am building a new multifunctional discord bot and i'm having some problems starting the command at the console                                                      **

````
  const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed() 
  .setTitle("Este es su título, puede contener 256 caracteres")
  .setAuthor(message.author.username, message.author.avatarURL)
  .setColor(0x00AE86)
  .setDescription("Este es el cuerpo principal del texto, puede contener 2048 caracteres.")
  .setFooter("Pie de página, puede contener 2048 caracteres", client.user.avatarURL)
  .setImage(message.author.avatarURL)
  .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL)
  .setTimestamp()
  .setURL("https://github.com/CraterMaik")
  .addField("Este es un título de campo, puede contener 256 caracteres",
    "Este es un valor de campo, puede contener 2048 caracteres.")
  .addField("Campo en línea", "Debajo del campo en línea", true)
  .addBlankField(true)
  .addField("Campo en línea 3", "Puede tener un máximo de 25 campos.", true);
  message.channel.send({embed})}```    





**When i start the comand, i get this error:**

*ReferenceError: message is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\leodu\OneDrive\Escritorio\bot2\punch.js:23:1)
  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1109:14)←[39m
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1138:10)←[39m  
  at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:989:32)←[39m*

Can someone tell me what I can fix in the code?
Thanks.
````

Comment: How are you assigning and passing `message`?

Comment: It looks like the error is not actually in the code you're sharing. Most likely you didn't define `message` or defined with another name eg `msg`

Comment: Make sure you are defining `message`. Maybe you have named it `msg` instead or if you are using a command handler you might not have passed `message` in the function parameters

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Firstly, If you are using discord.js V12+ I believe RichEmbed is deprecated and Discord.MessageEmbed() should be used instead (For more about MessagEmbed see the Discord.js docs: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed or the guide: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html).